# Python - Feeding links from csv to .py program

Tags: python

I have been working on a csv based image scraper using beautifulsoup. This is becuase the links have to be modified before downloading.

This is the basis of the code :

```
    import requests
    import csv
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib import urlretrieve
    import csv
    import os
    import sys


    url = '..............'


    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')

    with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
        bsoup_writer = csv.writer(f) 
        for link in soup.find_all('a',{'class': '........'}):
            bsoup_writer.writerow([link.get('href')])
```

This is just part of the main code and it works very well on the page/link you're at. With that said I would like to use other csv file (this would be the crawling file) with list of links to feed to this code/py program so it could download from each link in that csv file. Hence is it possible to modify the url  variable to call the csv file and iterate over the links in it?

Comment: just loop over the csv links and execute the python script using the url as argument,i.e.: `python script.py "https://somesite.com"` - http://www.diveintopython.net/scripts_and_streams/command_line_arguments.html

Comment: Try putting the scrapping in one function and saving to csv to another.